# Started "doing" Pythagorean theorem problems with isosceles triangles today ...

Tags: triangles

Yesterday, I solved my very first Pythagorean theorem problem! Everything was going good so far, I was solving harder problems very easily. However, today's lesson is a little bit different. I am working with isosceles triangles, and I have the following:

The two equal sides of the isosceles triangle are 25 cm long. The base, on the other hand, is 40 cm. I have to find the height of the triangle (CH).

So, I did the following:

(CH)2 + (AC)2 = (AB)2

(CH)2 + 625 = 1600

(CH)2 = 975

CH = 5 √ 39

Am I correct? Any kind of help is appreciated!

Comment: I assume you mean isosceles triangles?

Comment: Yes but I just figured out something! I should be using half of AC, instead of the whole side, I think.

Comment: $25^2-20^2=15^2$

Comment: @PlamenDobrev  Yes, the base of the triangle intersects with height (altitude). So  $\text{height}^2 + 20^2= 25^2$.  Solve for height.

Comment: I got it now, thank you @J.W Tanner and @amWhy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed in your comment, "I should be using half of AC, instead of the whole side".  Indeed.  Then you have a right triangle with one leg $20$, and the hypotenuse, say $AB$ of length $25$.

So we get the equation, to determine height, $$20^2 + \text{height}^2 = 25^2$$

Now you just need to solve for height: $$\text{height}^2 =  25^2 - 20^2.$$

Comment: Thanks a million! The question looks so dumb now but I couldn't really solve it without your help! Once again, thank you! Wish you a great day!

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you kept thinking about it, and commented after posting. That's the beauty of isosceles triangles: they're two right triangles, back-to-back! –

Comment: We can less find many persons who love teaching for its sake. They are just doing some maths in all levels.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done wrong is that you messed up with your notations! Let's keep them organized!

Denote your isosceles triangle as $\triangle ABC$ where

- $AB=40$ is the base,
- $CB=CA=25$ are the two sides of equal length,
- and $CH$ is the height that you want to find.

Notice that the point $H$ is the midpoint of the base $AB$. Now let's apply the Pythagorean theorem to the right triangle $\triangle CHA$:
$$
CH^2+AH^2=AC^2\;.
$$ 
Now substitution: $AH=\frac12 AB = 20$, $AC=25$. So
$$
CH^2 + 20^2 = 25^2
$$
which is $CH^2 +400=625$. Hence
$$
CH = \sqrt{225} = 15.
$$
Don't you get excited that the length is an integer?! :)

Comment: This a correct answer. Why downvote??